# "GENERAL FAILURE" when pinging to 127.0.0.1

Tags: windows-7, networking

My network adapter are enabled and I'm getting "GENERAL FAILURE" even when i ping to 127.0.0.1

This problem shows up after an unsuccessful installation of some firewall. I removed it and I still have the same problem.

Comment: any chance to post more details? maybe a screenshot of ipconfig /all

Comment: @Molly, sorry, no chances, i have even make an upgrade install and still having this problems, now i have a new copy of windows. i have tried everything ...

Comment: Had the same issue, found out that it was because a software named sentinel locked my network completely.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like the TCP stack might be corrupted.  If so, here is a potential fix:

1. Click the Start button, bottom-left of the screen
2. Type **cmd** into the Search programs and files box and press **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** (runs the command prompt as administator and bypasses UAC if enabled)
3. Type **netsh int ip reset reset.txt** and press **Enter**
4. Type **netsh winsock reset** and press **Enter**
5. Restart the computer

Failing that, pop in the Windows 7 install CD and cancel out of the installation wizard.  From the same command prompt as above, type **sfc /scannow** and press **Enter**.  Let it run through and restart.

Comment: this doesn't work, it seams i have installed an "IP filter driver" im looking how i can remove it.. i also heard about reinstalling the "tcp ip protocol driver" but in Windows7 its not simple

Comment: Windows key + R (to get the Run dialog box up) | control netconnections | right-click your usual network connection and click Properties | see if the IP filter driver is in the list and uncheck it | restart

Answer (score 0):

Is at least one network connection enabled?
Is your NIC enabled?
Does it work when you do it in safe mode with networking support?
Do you have any 3rd party NIC software? This is almost always useless.
Try restoring to a previous restore point.

Comment: i have tried restore the system but it doesn't work, and a have also uninstalled all 3rd party software and rebooted in "safe mode with networking". still have the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you can't ping 127.0.0.1 it sounds like your NIC is failing. Are you able to swap out the network card to test?

Did the problem just begin when you started to use Win7?

Edit: Based on your comment, have you tried a [system restore](http://www.technospot.net/blogs/how-to-do-a-system-restore-in-windows-vista-and-windows-7/) since the unsuccessfull firewall install?

Comment: all the network adapters report the same problem, im getting this message just after an unsuccessful installation of some firewall.

Comment: I think you have found your problem, then. Now just figure out how to remove that corpse of firewall installation.

Comment: Not to mention, loopback (127.0.0.1) never hits your NIC (there isn't even a loopback interface). It's handled internal to the Windows TCP/IP stack. Go ahead and run wireshark, and try to capture data going to 127.0.0.1. http://www.hsc.fr/ressources/articles/win_net_srv/missing_loopback.html